# Is it good idea to write own grid in my case?

Tags: javascript, datagrid

I need to do this data grid with sorting, AJAX, paging and loading variety data.

[image]

What is better customize exists grid(jqGrid, flexcGrid etc) or write my own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with your own ajax datagrid. I've wrote such an application with xajax and a nested xml datastructure. It's quite simple and you are more independent from the business side of your application (moneytize and personal contact). I can show you some examples.

Answer (score 0):

Start with using existing one - there's no point in reinventing the wheel. You will save much time and effort.

Write your own only if the existing components doesn't provide all the functionality you need. Your grid looks quite simple and standard - existing components will be enough. Style using CSS.

Comment: But i need to do same design. It might be hard task with 3d party grid.

Comment: What design are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

Give [Datatables](http://www.datatables.net/) a try

But in case you need the same styles and look and feel that would be difficult to attain with DataTables..

DataTables provides few its own styles and [CSS themes](http://www.datatables.net/styling/themes)...find the best suited

But this provides all the functionality you need and also is highly customizable...

Answer (score 0):

You need to look carefully at what is available, and make a decision based on what you can find.

If there is an existing product that does the functionality you require, and has the extensibility to allow you to achieve your requirements. If there is, then this will save you time, and mean that you don't have to support the coding that is already provided.

If you cannot find any such control, then write your own. Writing your own should be a second choice - not a last option, because it is significantly better that hacking an existing control to fit what you need, which will probably take longer.

It is a choice each time. There is no single best answer.