# Grid with sorting

Tags: c#, javascript

I'm writing my own gridview control. The problem is sorting. What is best practic to do that.

I can write function like that:

```
public object GetDataForGrid(int currentPage, int rowsPerPage, string sortColumnName, string sortDirection)
{

        if(sortColumnName="Date" && sortDirection=="ASC")
    {
       return Detalizations.OrderBy(x => x.Date).Skip(currentPage*rowsPerPage).ToList();
    }           

        .....
        //And over 9000 other branches
}
```

But ofcourse these solution is not optimal and looks oververbose. But how i can do it right?

---

Maybe reflection could help me?

Comment: Is this a universal grid, or one meant only for the `Detalizations` object?

Comment: Only for detalization object. Detalization is linq2sql autogenerated class

Comment: Why not use a premade component? Writing a gridview is very complicated. This problem is just the tip of an iceberg. If you're already having problems here...

Comment: @Vilx http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6855997/is-it-good-idea-to-write-own-grid-in-my-case

Comment: I don't understand. What's your point?

Comment: I need to do same design as you can see on the screenshot. Customizeble exists chart might take long time that's why i throught that write my own chart better idea then custom exists.

Comment: @Vilx- let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2096/discussion-between-neir0-and-vilx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what don't you use the  GridView.Sort Method  which is made for that scope

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.sort.aspx

have also a look at:

http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/gridview/Custom-GridView-with-Paging-and-Filtering.aspx#Custom_Filtering

another simple example

https://web.archive.org/web/20210323170551/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/012308-1.aspx

Comment: But i'm writing my OWN grid. I donnt use ASP.NET GridView

Answer (score 0):

If you're extending the GridView from the BCL you should look at the builtin Sort.  Otherwise, when the sort is changed get the Comparer for the datatype stored in that column (look at Comparer(T).Default), store it someplace, and apply the initial OrderBy to your rows.

Then when a row is updated or inserted, relocate that row based on the comparer that is currently set.

Comment: NO. It's my own grid. Not ASP.NET.

Comment: Then the rest of my answer beyond the first sentence still applies.